# draw graphs by tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am attempting to generate the following graph.
who draw graphs?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\def\r{4pt}
\def\dy{1cm}
\tikzstyle{c}=[draw,circle,fill=black,minimum size=\r,inner sep=0pt, anchor=center]
\tikzstyle{d}=[draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=\r,inner sep=0pt, anchor=center]

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]
  \draw (0,0)
    node [d] (C0) {}
    foreach \i in {1}
      {
        -- (0,\dy+\r) node (C\i) [d] {}
      };
  \draw (C1) ++(\dy+\r,0)
    node (C2) [d] {}
    foreach \i in {3}
      {
        -- (\dy+\r,0) node (C\i) [d] {}
      } 
     -- (C0) 
     (C1) -- (C2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}

\def\r{4pt}
\def\dy{1cm}
\tikzset{c/.style={draw,circle,fill=black,minimum size=\r,inner sep=0pt,
anchor=center},
d/.style={draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=\r,inner sep=0pt, anchor=center}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Ncorners}{3}
\node[draw, regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\Ncorners,minimum size=3cm] 
(poly\Ncorners) {};
\node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\Ncorners,minimum size=4.5cm] 
(outerpoly\Ncorners) {};
\foreach\x in {1,...,\Ncorners}{
    \node[d] (poly\Ncorners-\x) at (poly\Ncorners.corner \x){};
    \node[d] (outerpoly\Ncorners-\x) at (outerpoly\Ncorners.corner \x){};
    \draw (poly\Ncorners-\x) -- (outerpoly\Ncorners-\x);
}
\begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Ncorners}{4}
\node[draw, regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\Ncorners,minimum size=3cm] 
(poly\Ncorners) {};
\node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\Ncorners,minimum size=4.5cm] 
(outerpoly\Ncorners) {};
\foreach\x in {1,...,\Ncorners}{
    \node[d] (poly\Ncorners-\x) at (poly\Ncorners.corner \x){};
    \node[d] (outerpoly\Ncorners-\x) at (outerpoly\Ncorners.corner \x){};
    \draw (poly\Ncorners-\x) -- (outerpoly\Ncorners-\x);
}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=10cm]
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Ncorners}{5}
\node[draw, regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\Ncorners,minimum size=3cm] 
(poly\Ncorners) {};
\node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\Ncorners,minimum size=4.5cm] 
(outerpoly\Ncorners) {};
\foreach\x in {1,...,\Ncorners}{
    \node[d] (poly\Ncorners-\x) at (poly\Ncorners.corner \x){};
    \node[d] (outerpoly\Ncorners-\x) at (outerpoly\Ncorners.corner \x){};
    \draw (poly\Ncorners-\x) -- (outerpoly\Ncorners-\x);
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I used the opportunity to replace `\tikzstyle` by `\tikzset`.

Answer (score 6):

Just for fun, a single command code (only one `;`).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
  \tikz[
    poly/.style={regular polygon,minimum size=3cm},
    dot/.style={circle,inner sep=2pt,draw,fill=white}]
    \foreach \N in {3,4,5}
      \draw[regular polygon sides=\N,xshift=\N*7cm]
        node[poly,draw](S){} node[poly,scale=1.5](T){}
        foreach\i in{1,...,\N}{(S.corner \i) node[dot]{} -- (T.corner \i) node[dot]{}};
\end{document}
```

[image]